# What would you suggest as a start point to understand a 25k rows code?

Tags: javascript

I'm really confused here. I am trying to understand [this code](http://ajaxorg.github.com/ace/build/demo/kitchen-sink/kitchen-sink-uncompressed.js) (it's javascript) but I don't really know from where I should start. It's more than 25.000 rows including the comments. Therefore, reading the code line by line is definitely not the way to go. Using a debugger would be good, but I don't know any that works like Visual Studio debugger. So what else could I do to understand this code? What would be your starting point?

Comment: Usually there's some sort of documentation that accompanies large amounts of code like that, does it exist/have you looked at it?

Comment: @RobertRouhani, couldn't find any. Only found one for embedding the editor.

Comment: The code states it is an adaptation from AJAX's code editor.  In my opinion, it was editted to do programming language to language conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change something.

Find something you're interested in (something must be more interesting than "all of it"), and change it. Make it do something different.

Don't fixate on the 25K lines of code, rather fixate on the 2, 10, 100 lines that you care about first. Then, you will implicitly bump in to other parts of the system.

Once you're done, change something else. See what, if any, commonality exists between your two changes.

And just keep going. It's easier that way. Elephants taste better when eaten in small bites.

Comment: And also, it seems to be open source, so you could find an outstanding bug against the code and fix it. This will have other benefits. I always start by fixing bugs if I need to understand a large body of code.

Comment: Well, guess as Will says, trial and error seems to be the most effective way. It will take some time though :) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this instead: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/tree/master/lib/ace

That format should be much more approachable than all 25k LoC concatenated together. Having the filenames to help provide context is very helpful.

You can step through JavaScript code just like stepping through VB or C# code in Visual Studio. Take a look at the developer tools in your browser of choice - F12 will open them up in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. They will all have a section related to scripts, where you can set breakpoints, step through the code once paused, set watches, and most of the other things you're used to when debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, didn't see that link before! It's now much much much much more easier to understand. Thanks Dave! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can debug javascript in firefox's firebug with breakpoints.  This code looks like a library used to convert code from one language to another.  It is rather in depth and very well coded.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by finding a effect you want to figure out and off you go...

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the source https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/tree/master/lib/ace instead of the file with it all scrunched together... The file you linked is the final build, not the edited sources, If my quick glance is correct.